# When the ajax call is fully completed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

when any ajax call is done by clients , Clients  uploads data to server(HTTP  request) and then receive data from server(HTTP Response), when the data is received totally by clients,  the ajax request is consider successful and  success callback function is executed ,

But when i try to track ,this data transfer between client and server , by using `xhr` in `$.ajax` call

```
xhr: function(){
   
    var xhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr() ;
   
    xhr.upload.onprogress = function(e){console.log('upload progress',e.loaded/e.total*100) } ;
     xhr.onprogress =  function(e){console.log('total downloaded',e.loaded)}
    return xhr ;
```

In this ajax request , server is sending 277695 bytes file , But
The data is not completely downloaded, still it says  XHR finished loading , Why after some part is downloaded first , And XHR request is become complerted ,

[image]

We can see here server a is sending a file of length 277695 bytes ,  But only the 7946 bytes downloaded , and it says xhr finished loading , I was expecting , all file (277695 bytes)should be downloaded before XHR finsihed loading. So can someone explain why only some part of file is downloaded first ?

### UPDATE

And i also want to ask when the success call back function is executed, because it will be executed when whole result(response) received from server . So when the success callback function will be executed ? after total download is 7946, OR after the whole data  downloaded , i.e total downloaded is 277695

Comment: Try using `xhr.addEventListener("load", transferCompleteCallback);` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest

Comment: @rafaelcastrocouto  Thanks  using `xhr.addEventListener("load", transferCompleteCallback)` the call back function is executed when the whole data(277695bytes) is recived from the server , So that mean xhr request is fully completed after the whole data is recived from the server ,, But i still not sure what is the meaning of `XHR Finished loading` after only 7946 data is recived

Comment: Where do you output that to the console? Probably all data is received between the previous log of 7946 bytes and that log.

Comment: @trincot I cosole.log()  is automatically triggred by the  xhr.onprogress function. see the xhr: function()

Comment: Those `console.log` do not output that line `XHR finished...`

Comment: Sorry , I don't know what outputs  this line  `XHR finished.. .`, Can u please explain me little more , u can see i am a beginner, I don't know what u mean by this `Where do you output that to the console?` @trincot

Comment: Probably it is a log made by the network monitoring that is part of your console. The point is that this log is made almost at the same time that the true complete transfer has happened, not immediately(!) after the 7946 bytes were read. In short, it is OK like it is. Just use the `load` event, which triggers immediately(!) after you get the `XHR finished` message.

Comment: @trincot Now i get it , Thank u so much, , u can write it as a answer ,  I will mark it as accepted , Thanks again :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The log `XHR finished loading...` is made by the network monitoring that is part of your console. The point is that this log is made almost at the same time that the true complete transfer has happened, not immediately(!) after the 7946 bytes were read. In short, it is OK like it is. Just use the `load` event, which triggers immediately(!) after you get the XHR finished message.

Answer (score 1):

Use the XHR "load" event listener:

```
 xhr.addEventListener("load", transferCompleteCallback);
```

Read more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest